# Add text after index

Tags: indexing

I am seeking a "`\indexepilogue`"-like command or method equivalent to `\indexprologue` of `imakeidx` but *after* the index and before any page break is made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`etoolbox` package can add code to the end of `theindex` environment, but what code to add depends on the specifics of your case. Please add a small working example showing what you intend and what you have tried so far, which class, which packages.

Here is a 'plain' version:

[image: plain]

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand\epcode{This is some text after the index.}
\makeindex
\AtEndEnvironment{theindex}{\epcode}

\begin{document}
Test A\index{A}
\newpage
Test B\index{B}
\newpage
\printindex
\end{document}
```

With `imakeidx` with two-column mode, with text in column two:

[image: two column index plus text]

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand\epcode{This is some text after the index.}
\makeindex
\AtEndEnvironment{theindex}{\epcode}

\begin{document}
Test A\index{A}
\newpage
Test B\index{B}
\newpage
\printindex
\end{document}
```

A variation, showing the difference between `AtEnd...` and `AfterEnd...`:

[image: two column one column]

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand\epcode{This is some text after the index, but before the end of its environemnt (two balanced columns).}
\newcommand\epcodeb{And this is some text after the end of the index environment.}
\makeindex
\AtEndEnvironment{theindex}{\epcode}\AfterEndEnvironment{theindex}{\epcodeb}

\begin{document}
Test A\index{A}
\newpage
Test B\index{B}
\newpage
\printindex
\end{document}
```